# How do I suppress warnings when compiling a Business Central Extension

Tags: visual-studio-code, dynamics-business-central, dynamics-al

I'd like to disable the warning AL1025, because of the nature of the AL compiler, I get a lot of warnings related to my `node_modules` folder. Apparently, it [should be possible](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dynamics365-release-plan/2020wave2/smb/dynamics365-business-central/suppress-al-warnings) to suppress warnings in the app.json like this

```
  "suppressWarnings": ["AL1025"]
```

But I still get those warnings:

```
Microsoft (R) AL Compiler version 7.4.7.43721
Copyright (C) Microsoft Corporation. All rights reserved

Compilation started for project 'ABC Sample Ext' containing '11' files at '19:58:7.337'.

/Users/username/Dev/abc-workspace/abc-sample/node_modules/he/LICENSE-MIT.txt(1,1): warning AL1025: The file at location '/Users/username/Dev/abc-workspace/abc-sample/node_modules/he/LICENSE-MIT.txt' does not match any definition.
```

What am I doing wrong?

Answer (score 5):

You need to define a ruleset that tells the compiler which warnings/errors to ignore.

There are two parts to this:

1. Define the ruleset
2. Activate the ruleset

The ruleset is defined in JSON format with a `name`, `description` and collection of `rules`. A rule must have an `id`, a `description` and `justification`.

An example could be:

```
{
    "name": "Custom ruleset",
    "description": "Set some rules as hidden",
    "rules": [
        {
            "id": "AL1025",
            "action": "Info",
            "justification": "Allow non-AL files in workspace"           
        }
    ]
}
```

Then you need to activate the rules you defined. This is done by defining `al.ruleSetPath` in your `settings.json` (in the `.vscode` folder):

```
{
    "al.ruleSetPath": "./custom.ruleset.json"
}
```

Comment: +1 for the workaround but I rather would like to get the `suppressWarnings` attribute of the `app.json` working.

Comment: I guess there might be a dependency to the version of Business Central you are using. Which version is that?